# define a type that complies to interface A or B

Tags: typescript

Here is my code

```
interface Car {
  a: string
  b: string
  c: string
}

interface Bus {
  b: string
  c: string
  d: string
}


let carOrBus = {a, b, c} 
let carOrBus = {b, c, d}
```

how can I type `carOrBus` for the two above assignments to work ?

Comment: Why not `Car | Bus`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should work
`let carOrBus: Car | Bus = {a, b, c}`